# unable to run sharepoint powershell script from sql server agent job

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sharepoint

I have a powershell script which is working fine from PowerShell ISE, the script will move the local files to SharePoint 365 documents. When I schedule a SQL server agent job using this script getting the error below.
Please advice me what I need to do to run this script.

> abc\SQLServiceAcc. A job step received an error at line 10 in a
>   PowerShell script. The corresponding line is 'Add-Type -Path
>   "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"'. Correct the
>   script and reschedule the job. The error information returned by
>   PowerShell is: 'Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program
>   Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll' or one of its
>   dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the
>   currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.  '.  Process Exit Code
>   -1.  The step failed.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you are running the script and which version of SQL Server you are using.

Look at http://www.travisgan.com/2013/05/sql-server-agent-job-and-powershell.html